# Plot segment between point and line

Tags: r, plot, line, linear-regression

I have the following dataset:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- c(1, 2, 1.3, 3.75, 2.25)
```

And I need to draw the straight line that fits my dataset by using simple regression, as well as these points:

```
plot(x, y, pch=19, ylim=c(0,6))
xx <- seq(0, 6, length=100)
fit <- lm(y~x)
lines(xx, predict(fit, data.frame(x=xx)))
```

Now I would like to join the points in the plot to the line as in the following (example) picture, showing the related prediction error:

[image]

How can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using base `r` you could do the following:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- c(1, 2, 1.3, 3.75, 2.25)

fit <- lm(y ~ x)
plot(x, y)
abline(fit)
res <- signif(residuals(fit), 5)
pre <- predict(fit)
segments(x, y, x, pre, col = rainbow(length(x)))
```

[image: plot]

Adding labels is easy with `calibrate::textxy`:

```
# install.packages("calibrate")
library(calibrate)
textxy(x, y, res)
```

[image: plot with labels]

Answer (score 1):

I like the `broom` package for generating a nice data frame for things like this:

```
library(broom)
aug_fit = broom::augment(fit)

with(aug_fit, segments(x0 = x, y0 = y, x1 = x, y1 = .fitted))
```

Running my `with(... segments())` line after your plot yields:

[image]

I'll leave adding colors, text labels, etc. to you.

Answer (score 0):

Using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

#ggplot needs a dataframe
dat <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
fit <- lm(y~x,data=dat)

#add predicted y for each x, to enable segment drawing
dat$pred <- predict(fit, dat)

with thanks to JasonAizkalns: adding labels too
dat$pred <- predict(fit, dat)
dat$pred_error <- dat$y - dat$pred 
dat$vjust <- sign(dat$pred_error)*-1.1 #labels can appear above/below points now

  p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x,y=y, color=factor(x)))+
  geom_point(size=2) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=x,xend=x,y=y,yend=pred)) +
  geom_abline(intercept=coefficients(fit)[1],slope=coefficients(fit)[2]) +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(pred_error,2),vjust=vjust))+
  ylim(c(0,5))+
  xlim(c(0,5))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="none")
p1
```

[image]

Comment: I've edited the answer, thanks. Generally in geom_text I like to map labels inside the aes and set things that are always the same out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Another `ggplot2` answer., and similar in spirit to Gregors answer. This makes use of `fortify.lm`, where you can pass the results from an`lm` regression to `ggplot`.  To see what fortify does, you can look at the object `fortify(fit)`.

```
# Your data and linear model
x <- 1:5
y <- c(1, 2, 1.3, 3.75, 2.25)
fit <- lm(y~x)

# Plot
library(ggplot2)    

ggplot(fit, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=x, yend=y, col=factor(x), label=round(.resid, 2))) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_line(aes(x=x, y=.fitted), inherit.aes=FALSE) +
     geom_segment(aes(y=.fitted)) +
     geom_text(aes(vjust=-1*sign(.resid))) +
     theme(legend.position="none")
```